# How to password protect writing to a file but not reading to the file

Tags: terminal, mac, security, password, permission

**Purpose**: limit writing to `/etc/hosts` to prevent me from editing the file without permission from someone that I entrust the password to. Note that I am the administrator of this Mac, so the password protection should prevent me from (or make it *very* difficult to) edit the file without the password.

**Desired effect**: If I try to edit the file with `sudo vim /etc/hosts` or something of the like, it should not only prompt me for the admin password for the `sudo` call but also prompt me for a password I set for the file. However, reading the file should not be restricted as various processes need access to this file.

**Unsuccessful attempts**:

1. I haven't tried creating a separate password-protected disk image to move `/etc/hosts` onto, but I'm quite sure that is not going to work.
2. [A similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/810508/password-protect-hosts-file-without-encrypting-it) was posed on AskUbuntu but the posted answer is not what I am looking for.

Note: This is my first ever question, so please let me know if I should make any edits. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, interesting question. My first thought had been a password protected disk image, but I've never tested that approach with `/etc/hosts`. Can I ask for an example of the types of processes which need access to the file?

Comment: @Monomeeth My understanding is that the hosts file allows you to override part of the DNS for your local machine (please correct if I am misunderstanding) so network-related processes will need read-access. However, I haven't tested this so I am not sure... Here is [IBM documentation on hosts file format](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=formats-hosts-file-format-tcpip) which may be helpful in understanding how it works.

Comment: To remove editing of the `hosts` file, you’ll need to remove access to `sudo`. You’re not editing the file, the root user is.  You could create a rule in `sudoers` that prevents you from using `vi` or `nano` as root but that will break those tools for everything else as well.  Your only chose is to become a standard user and give someone else admin rights

Comment: Thank you. @Allan is there no way to prevent the root user to write to a file without a password, in that case? Or is the only path forward to become a standard user?

Comment: It’s a chicken/egg problem. The moment you pw protect a file, it’s encrypted; even if using the least secure encryption possible. There’s no way for a file to be open for reading but locked for saving. It’s also important to note that the hosts file needs to be both readable *and* writable by the system.  Putting a password would break that

Comment: General rule of thumb:  *what one admin can do, another can undo*. If you want to prevent a behavior, you have to remove the ability (rights/permission) to execute said behavior.  So, unfortunately, yes, you need to be a standard user